# XlsxWriter - Line with Gradient Fill

Tags: xlsxwriter

I am trying to plot the light spectrum with the XlsxWriter library.

For this I would like to color the line with a gradient. Unfortunately this does not work for me, the line stays in the default color.

This is the code I tried:

```
    spectrumplot.add_series({
        'categories': '=Spektrum!$B$1:$CD$1',
        'values': '=Spektrum!$B$2:$CD$2',
        'gradient': {
            'colors': ['#B000AE', '#FF00FC', '#0000FF', '#00FFFF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FFA200', '#FF0000', '#000000'],
            'positions': [0,        5,         17,       26,         37,         50,         56,         76,       100],
            'angle': 0.001}
    })
```

Using spectrumplot.set_plotarea() to color the background works, but I would like to color the line itself.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Currently gradient fill isn't supported for lines in XlsxWriter charts although it is supported for many other chart elements. If you open a feature request on GitHub I can add it to the backlog.

Update: Feature request: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/868